# Swiper.js is laggy on Android with free mode, loop, and auto play

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, swiper.js

Recently, a lot of applications start to feature this kind of UI on their page:

A scrollable, looped, while autoplay swiper (an example screenshot from the app [infltr](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/infltr-infinite-filters/id935623257))

https://youtube.com/shorts/Qmlve7qS22o?feature=share

I tried to implement the same component in my React project.

After trials, I found [Swiper.js](https://swiperjs.com/) could be the closest key to the door with `freeMode`, `loop` and `autoPlay`

My settings are as follows:

```js
const swiperSetting = {
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    spaceBetween: 10,
    longSwipes: false,
    grabCursor: true,
    centeredSlides: true,
    freeMode: {
      enabled: true,
      momentumBounce: false,
    },
    loop: true,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 0,
      disableOnInteraction: false
    },
    speed: 5000,
  };
```

The result is like the following: (screenshot of Pixel 3A XL, Android 10)

https://youtube.com/shorts/qkSPWNX9YXk?feature=share

As you can see from the above clip, there's an obvious latency between finger touch and the animation of the swiper.

However, this laggy condition wasn't seen on Pixel 6, Android 12, or iOS devices

Pixel 3a XL is a 2019 product, not a low-end device, so I don't expect that this component would be so laggy on this device.

Any suggestion on how to better tune Swiper.js? 
Or, is it an inevitable bug on the older versions of Android devices? 
Or, there's some other solution better fits my need?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a css rule that has bad performance while swiping.

```
filter: drop-shadow( ... );
```

Removing all occurences of that css rule inside of the elements inside of swiper fixed it for me.

Comment: While this is the actual cause of the problem, this is incomplete. In my case, this rule was applied to some parent element of the slider, not child.

Answer (score 0):

Activate the parameter cssmode will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following code to the CSS:

```
.swiper-container {
  transform: none;
}
```

Had the same problem (glitched Slider) and this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar lag issue (on Android). In a simple page, I had a slider and it caused the page scroll to be laggy. The slider itself was also laggy. I tried the solutions mentioned here, but none really worked. The problem was with Tailwind CSS.

It seems that I used `drop-shadow` instead of `shadow` on some card element. The slider was inside this card. `drop-shadow` uses the `filter` property. This was the cause. Switching to `shadow` (that is `box-shadow`) solved the issue.

Comment: Very impressive. Since I don't have Android device now, so it's a pity that I cannot go through all the possible solutions above.